# GCC/G++ encrypting with preprocessor

Tags: mingw, preprocessor

is it possible to encrypt strings with preprocessor?
for examle:

```
*data section*
--------------
"test string1"
"test string2"
"test stringN"
...
```

after compiling program, they will become random encrypted strings. like:

```
*data section*
-------------
"ioasfj)@*(Ug"
"JS8a9fjsa()S"
"zl)I@dXaskdQ"
...
```

is it possible without any addons?

Comment: Do you actually mean encrypted or simply randomised?

Comment: Encrypted, for example simple XOR encryption, on runtime, it will decrypt data from TLS callback or from entry point, doesn't matter. I'm just trying to understand how could I encrypt strings from preprocessor instead of runtime.

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1381818/is-the-c-preprocessor-able-to-process-strings-char-by-char

Comment: Definitely, thanks for info ;-)