# How to make sure that your code is secure?

Tags: reverse-engineering, piracy-prevention

I am a programmer. I have about 5 years experience of programming in different kind of languages. I was concerning about my code speed, about optimizing the memory that uses my code, and about good coding style and so on. But have never thought how secure my code is. So I have disassembled my code to see what can do a hacker. Would it be easy to crack my code? 
And I saw that it is! It is very easy, because I was storing

1. serial number as a string
2. encryption-decryption codes as well

So if someone has the minimal knowledge of assembler he/she can just simple dissembler and after 10-20 minutes of debugging my code is cracked!!! Even it could be done by opening the exe with notepad I guess! :-)

So what I am asking are the following:

1. Where I should store that kind of secure information’s?
2. What are the common strategies of delivering a secure code?

Comment: I would call it protected code. Secure usually means prone to vulnerabilities.

Comment: Go OpenSource :) Or webapps, it's the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing you must realize is that you'll never prevent a determined reverser from cracking any protection schemes because anything that the code can do, the reverser will  eventually find out how to replicate it. The only way you can achieve any sort of reliable protection is to have the shipped program be nothing more than a dumb client and have the brunt of the software on some server the reverser has no access to.

With that out of the way, you can certainly make it *harder* for a would be reverser to break your protections. [Obfuscation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obfuscation)  is the sort of first step in achieving this. I have no experience using obfuscators but I'm sure you can find some suggestions for some on SO. Also if you're using a lower level language like C/C++, simply compiling the code with full optimization and stripping all debugging symbols gets you a decent amount of obfuscation.

I read [this article](http://www.gamecareerguide.com/features/20011017/dodd_01.htm) a few years ago, but I still think it's techniques hold up today. It's one of the developers of a video game called Spyro talking about the set of techniques they used to prevent piracy. They claim it wasn't until 3 months after the release that a cracked version became available, which is fairly impressive.

Answer (score 1):

If you are concerned about piracy, then there are many avenues you can take. Making the code security tighter (obfuscation, license codes, binding the software to a particular PC, hardware/dongle protection, etc) is one, but it's worth bearing in mind that *every* piece of software can be cracked if someone sufficiently talented can be bothered.

Another approach is to consider the pricing model for your software. If you charge $1000 a copy, then there is a big incentive for someone to have a go at cracking it. If you only charge $5 then why should anyone bother to crack it?

So what is needed is a balance. Even the most basic protection will stop ordinary people making casual copies. Beyond that, simple techniques (obfuscation and license codes) and a sensible pricing strategy will hold most would-be crackers at bay by making it not worth the bother of cracking. After that, you start getting into ever more sophisticated techniques (dongles/CDs needing to be present to run the software, only being able to run the software after logging on to an online licensing system) that take a lot of effort/cost to implement and significantly increase the risk of annoying genuine customers (remember how annoyed everyone got when they bought half life but it wouldn't let them play the game?) - unless you have a popular mainstream product (i.e. a huge revenue stream to protect), there probably isn't much point going to that much effort.

Answer (score 1):

Make it web app.

Comment: Web applications can't be reverse-engineered.

Answer (score 1):

It will generally not be well-protected unless there's an external service doing the checking that you are in control of - and that service can still be spoofed by those who really wants to "crack" it. Instead, trust the customer and provide only minimal copyright protection. I'm sure there was an article or podcast about this by Joel Spolsky somewhere... here's another [related SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291762/how-to-avoid-piracy-when-shipping-source-code).

I have no idea if it will help but Windows provides (since 2000) a mechanism to retrieve and store encrypted information and you can also salt this storage on a per-application basis if needed: Data Protection API ([DPAPI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms995355.aspx))

This is on a machine or a user level but storing serials and perhaps some keys using it might be better than having them hidden in the application?

Answer (score 1):

What sort of secure are you talking about? 
Secure from the perspective that you are guarding your users data well? If so, study some real cryptography and utilize **Existing** libraries to encrypt your data. The win32 API is pretty good for this.

But if you're talking about stopping a cracker from stealing your application? There are many methods, but just give up. They slow crackers down, they don't stop them.

Answer (score 0):

Look at [How to hide a string in binary code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1356896/how-to-hide-a-string-in-binary-code) question

Comment: He wants to hide the *encryption/decryption functions*

Answer (score 0):

A simple technique for doing this is  to xor over all your code and xor back when you need it... but this needs an innate knowledge of assembly... I'm not sure, but you could try this:

```
void (*encryptionFunctn)(void);
void hideEncryptnFunctn(void)
{
    volatile char * i;
    while(*i!=0xC0) // 0xC0 is the opcode for ret
    {
        *i++^=0x45; // or any other code
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First you have to define what your code should be secure against, being secure as such is meaningless.

You seem to be worried about reverse engineering and users generating license codes without paying, though you don't say so. To make this harder you can obfuscate your code and key information in various ways. There area also techniques to make the use of debuggers harder, to prevent the reverse engineer from stepping through the code and seeing the information in clear.
But this only makes reverse engineering somewhat harder, not impossible

Another common security threat is execution of unwanted code, for example via buffer overflows.

Comment: I have described my question enough in details I think.

Answer (score 0):

To prevent against hackers viewing your code, you should use an obfuscator. An obfuscator will use various techniques which make it extremely difficult to make sense of the obfuscated code. Some techniques used are string encryption, symbol renaming, control flow obfuscation, etc. Check out [Crypto Obfuscator](http://www.ssware.com/cryptoobfuscator/obfuscator-net.htm) which additionally also has external method call hiding, Anti-Reflector, Anti-Debugging, etc

The goal is to erect as many obstacles as possible in the path of a would-be hacker.