# C++ macro to convert a string to list of characters

Tags: c++, c, macros

Is it possible to have a macro to have:

CHAR_LIST(chicken)

to expand to:

'c', 'h', 'i', 'c', 'k', 'e', 'n'

[Reason I want it: because for even moderate-sized strings, a macro is hugely more convenient than manually expanding. And the reason I need to expand is passing in a string to a varidiac template]

Comment: And you need a variadic template here because.....

Comment: Have you tried creating some kind of macro in your text editor to do this for you?

Comment: I'm currently working on a solution, but why exactly do you need to pass this to a variadic template? This might be important.

Comment: @Xeo, I'm trying to do string-switching at compile time -- and the case statements are like case_statement<'c', 'h', 'i', 'c', 'k', 'e', 'n'>(...functor if this case is true...)

Comment: @Heptic: Is it okay if you only have an array that you can iterate? :)

Comment: @Xeo: No, not really :(. I'm doing some TMP, so just need a macro to make it look a little nicer. :D

Comment: @Heptic: I meant an array as a **template argument** to your function. :) Imagine `['a','b','c','d']` to be the array, you'd get `case_statement<['a','b','c','d']>(...)`.

Comment: This would also be useful for [hiding strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1356896/how-to-hide-a-string-in-binary-code)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*Update by the answerer, July 2015: Due to the comments above on the question itself, we can see the the real question was not about macros per se. The real problem the questioner wanted to solve was to be able to pass a literal string to a template that accepts a series of chars as non-type template arguments. Here is an [ideone](http://ideone.com/QvXuYf) demo of a solution to that problem. The implementation there requires C++14, but it's easy to convert it to C++11.*

### ------------

I think we need a clearer example of how this macro is to be used. We need an example of the variadic template. (Another **Update**: This <strike>won't work</strike> doesn't work for me on g++ 4.3.3 in a variadic template even when c++0x support is turned on, but I think it might be interesting anyway.)

```
#include<iostream> // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6190963/c-macro-to-convert-a-string-to-list-of-characters
#include "stdio.h"

using namespace std;

#define TO_STRING(x) #x
#define CHAR_LIST_7(x)   TO_STRING(x)[0] \
                       , TO_STRING(x)[1] \
                       , TO_STRING(x)[2] \
                       , TO_STRING(x)[3] \
                       , TO_STRING(x)[4] \
                       , TO_STRING(x)[5] \
                       , TO_STRING(x)[6] \

int main() {
        cout << TO_STRING(chicken) << endl;
        printf("%c%c%c%c%c%c%c", CHAR_LIST_7(chicken));
}
```

The line defining `d` is what you're interested in. I've included other examples to show how it's built up. I'm curious about @GMan's link to automate the counting process.

Comment: Very interesting, if this can be extended to automatically count the string length it would seem to be the solution :)

/me goes to try

Comment: This macro can be used as an array initialiser, but not in a variadic template.

Comment: Actually it does work in variadic templates. Example: http://hpaste.org/47313/exand

Comment: @Heptic, I keep getting `error: an array reference cannot appear in a constant-expression` errors. What compiler you using? I'm on g++ (Ubuntu 4.3.3-5ubuntu4) 4.3.3 with --std=gnu++0x

Answer (score 2):

Nope, sorry, can't be done. There is no operation to split a string into characters. The closest you could get is through recursive metaprogramming, but that will give you the array as an object, not the actual text representation.

Comment: +1: The other alternative is an independent code-generation step in your build process.

Comment: That would be best if it was *really* needed, and somehow I don't think having `'c', 'h', 'i', 'c', 'k', 'e', 'n'` in the code is worth the trouble :)

Comment: There is an operation to split into chars. See my (klunky) answer. -1 for undue pessimism - I hope this appears reasonable.

Comment: @Aaron, maybe you didn't see a comment to an answer that was deleted where Heptic explained that these characters were meant to be template parameters. Your answer doesn't work in that case, making this answer the more correct one. Not deserving of a -1.

Comment: I'm undoing my downvote. I still think the answer should explain why, rather than just saying "Nope, sorry, can't be done". I've seen this a few times on SO, without basis. I'd never noticed Blindy on SO before. I think I'll trust @Blindy in future :-)

Comment: The solution below actually does work on template parameters, so it seems like there's a solution. Now the problem is just automatic length counting

Comment: That's exactly the part you can't do, you can't get how many characters there are in a string at compile time as text (not to be confused with the metaprogramming `sizeof` approach).

Comment: Wouldn't the `char` just after the end be '\0'? Maybe this can be used to terminate the template, with a specialization. If that worked, then you could just pass in TO_STRING(x)[0] all the way to TO_STRING(x)[100] without difficulty. I'd try it myself, but even the basic example from @Heptic doesn't compile for me.