# C++ how to speed up (with x86 SIMD) batch variable length integer encoding / decoding (runnable benchmark)

Tags: c++, optimization, encoding, compression, simd

I have this encoding method that works by encoding small blocks of 16x `int64_t` to a small block of 16 flag nibbles packed into 8 bytes, followed by 1 or more bytes of payload for each input `int64_t`:

- Use a nibble (4 bits) to represent `flag`
- Reserve 1 byte for `flag` (1 byte can store flags of 2 values)
- Store `sign(value)` in flag (high bit in the nibble)
- Store `abs(value)` in the buffer, variable number of bytes
- Store number of bytes needed in  flag.  (3 lower bits in the nibble)

---

This example benchmark is simplified. I have tested and for my use case with actual data: it's faster than LEB128 (aka varint) and lz4 and also compress better. So let's focus on this encoding method or something similar.

How can I improve this code? **I mostly care about decompression speed**. Some changes to the encode/decode format (or another format) is possible if that improves speed. I wonder if SIMD can be used in this case.

**Special note:**

- Most `abs(value)` has length <= 2 bytes.
- 99% of the time, 4 consecutive `abs(value)` can be represented by <= 7 bytes. Similarly, 99% of the time, 16 consecutive `abs(value)` can be represented by <= 31 byte.
- The 2 important functions are `encode` and `decode_original`

```
//  ##### from @aqrit's answer, tweaked by @petercordes #######

#include <cstddef>  // size_t
#include <cstdint> // uint64_t, int64_t
#include <immintrin.h> // lzcnt intrinsic
#include <cstring> // memcpy

unsigned char* encode_buf_bmi(size_t n, const int64_t* src, unsigned char* dst) {
    unsigned char* key_ptr = dst;
    size_t num_chunks = n >> 3;
    unsigned char* data_ptr = &dst[(num_chunks * 3) + ((((n & 0x7) * 3) + 7) >> 3)];
    while (num_chunks--) {
        uint64_t key = 0;
        for (size_t i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            uint64_t v = (uint64_t)*src++;
            memcpy(data_ptr, &v, sizeof(v)); // assumes little endian.

            v = (v + v) ^ v; // clear redundant sign bits (and trash everything else)
            v = (v << 8) | v; // combine lengths of 7 and 8
            v = (_lzcnt_u64(v | 1) ^ 63) >> 3; // use BSR on intel... 
            data_ptr += v + ((v + 1) >> 3); // key of 7 is length of 8
            key |= v << (i * 3);
        }
        memcpy(key_ptr, &key, 3); // assumes little endian.  Probably faster with overlapping 4-byte stores, except for the last chunk to avoid stepping on data
        key_ptr += 3;
    }
    // TODO: tail loop...
    
    return data_ptr;  // end of used part of buffer
}
    
void decode_buf_bmi(size_t n, const unsigned char* src, int64_t* dst) {
    const unsigned char* key_ptr = src;
    size_t num_chunks = n >> 3;
    const unsigned char* data_ptr = &src[(num_chunks * 3) + ((((n & 0x7) * 3) + 7) >> 3)];
    if (n >= 19) { // if has at least 8 bytes of padding before data_ptr
        data_ptr -= sizeof(uint64_t); // left aligned the truncated val in register (little endian) 
        while (num_chunks--) {
            unsigned keys;
            //memcpy(&keys, key_ptr, 3);   // big slowdown with GCC13.2: like 258 ms per buffer on Skylake 3.9GHz,  n_msg = 100'000'000
        memcpy(&keys, key_ptr, 4);     // 138 ms per buffer with 4-byte loads.  (Clang 16: 138 ms per buffer either way.)
            key_ptr += 3;
            for (size_t i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
                uint64_t v;
                size_t k = keys & 0x07;
                size_t len = k + ((k + 1) >> 3); // k==7 is len=8
                uint64_t mask = (uint64_t)0 - ((k + 7) >> 3); // k ? -1 : 0
                size_t shift = (64 - (len * 8)) & (size_t)mask; 

                keys >>= 3;     
                data_ptr += len; 
                memcpy(&v, data_ptr, sizeof(v));
                v &= mask;
                *dst++ = (int64_t)v >> shift;
            }
        }
        data_ptr += sizeof(uint64_t);
    }

    // TODO: tail loop...
}


// ############## From @Soonts' answer ##############
#include <immintrin.h>
#include <stdint.h>

// Exclusive prefix sum of unsigned bytes
// When the sum of all bytes exceeds 0xFF, the output is garbage
// Which is fine here because our bytes are in [0..8] interval
inline __m128i exclusivePrefixSum( const __m128i src, size_t& sum )
{
    __m128i v = src;
    // https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prefix_sum#/media/File:Hillis-Steele_Prefix_Sum.svg
    v = _mm_add_epi8( v, _mm_slli_si128( v, 1 ) );
    v = _mm_add_epi8( v, _mm_slli_si128( v, 2 ) );
    v = _mm_add_epi8( v, _mm_slli_si128( v, 4 ) );
    v = _mm_add_epi8( v, _mm_slli_si128( v, 8 ) );

    // So far we have computed inclusive prefix sum
    // Keep the last byte which is total sum of bytes in the vector
    uint16_t tmp = _mm_extract_epi16( v, 7 );
    tmp >>= 8;
    sum = tmp;

    // Subtract original numbers to make exclusive sum = byte offsets to load
    return _mm_sub_epi8( v, src );
}

// Load 4 uint64 numbers from ( rsi + offsets[ i ] ), keep the lowest bits[ i ] bits in the numbers
inline __m256i loadAndMask( const uint8_t* rsi, uint32_t offsets, __m128i bits )
{
    // Load 4 uint64_t numbers from the correct locations, without AVX2 gathers
    const int64_t* s0 = (const int64_t*)( rsi + (uint8_t)offsets );
    const int64_t* s1 = (const int64_t*)( rsi + (uint8_t)( offsets >> 8 ) );
    const int64_t* s2 = (const int64_t*)( rsi + (uint8_t)( offsets >> 16 ) );
    const int64_t* s3 = (const int64_t*)( rsi + ( offsets >> 24 ) );
    __m256i r = _mm256_setr_epi64x( *s0, *s1, *s2, *s3 );

    // Mask away the higher pieces in the loaded numbers
    __m256i shift = _mm256_cvtepu8_epi64( bits );
    const __m256i ones = _mm256_set1_epi32( -1 );
    __m256i mask = _mm256_sllv_epi64( ones, shift );
    return _mm256_andnot_si256( mask, r );
}

inline __m256i applySigns( __m256i v, __m128i signs )
{
    // Sign extend the masks from bytes to int64
    __m256i mask = _mm256_cvtepi8_epi64( signs );
    // Conditionally negate the numbers
    __m256i neg = _mm256_sub_epi64( _mm256_setzero_si256(), v );
    return _mm256_blendv_epi8( v, neg, mask );
}

class BlockDecoder
{
    // Load offsets, in bytes
    __m128i offsetBytes;
    // Payload bits per element, the bytes are in [ 0 .. 64 ] interval
    __m128i payloadBits;
    // 16 bytes with the 0x80 bit set when the corresponding input was negative; the rest of the bits are unused
    __m128i signs;
    // Count of payload bytes in the complete block
    size_t payloadBytes;

    // Decode the block header
    inline void loadHeader( const uint8_t* rsi )
    {
        // Load 8 bytes, and zero extend them into uint16_t
        const __m128i v = _mm_cvtepu8_epi16( _mm_loadu_si64( rsi ) );

        // Unpack lengths
        const __m128i seven = _mm_set1_epi8( 7 );
        const __m128i l4 = _mm_slli_epi16( v, 4 );
        __m128i lengths = _mm_or_si128( v, l4 );
        lengths = _mm_and_si128( lengths, seven );
        // Transform 7 into 8
        __m128i tmp = _mm_cmpeq_epi8( lengths, seven );
        lengths = _mm_sub_epi8( lengths, tmp );

        // Byte offsets to load 16 numbers, and count of payload bytes in the complete block
        offsetBytes = exclusivePrefixSum( lengths, payloadBytes );
        // Count of payload bits in the loaded numbers, lengths * 8
        payloadBits = _mm_slli_epi16( lengths, 3 );
        // Signs vector, we only use the highest 0x80 bit in these bytes
        signs = _mm_or_si128( _mm_slli_epi16( v, 8 ), l4 );
    }

    // Decode and store 4 numbers
    template<int slice>
    inline void decodeSlice( int64_t* rdi, const uint8_t* payload ) const
    {
        uint32_t off;
        __m128i bits, s;
        if constexpr( slice != 0 )
        {
            off = (uint32_t)_mm_extract_epi32( offsetBytes, slice );
            constexpr int imm = _MM_SHUFFLE( slice, slice, slice, slice );
            bits = _mm_shuffle_epi32( payloadBits, imm );
            s = _mm_shuffle_epi32( signs, imm );
        }
        else
        {
            off = (uint32_t)_mm_cvtsi128_si32( offsetBytes );
            // For the first slice of the block, the 4 lowest bytes are in the correct locations already
            bits = payloadBits;
            s = signs;
        }

        __m256i v = loadAndMask( payload, off, bits );
        v = applySigns( v, s );
        _mm256_storeu_si256( ( __m256i* )rdi, v );
    }

public:

    // Decode and store a block of 16 numbers, return pointer to the next block
    const uint8_t* decode( int64_t* rdi, const uint8_t* rsi )
    {
        loadHeader( rsi );
        rsi += 8;

        decodeSlice<0>( rdi, rsi );
        decodeSlice<1>( rdi + 4, rsi );
        decodeSlice<2>( rdi + 8, rsi );
        decodeSlice<3>( rdi + 12, rsi );

        return rsi + payloadBytes;
    }
};


//   ############ reference version and updated benchmark framework ###########
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <chrono>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

// https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xorshift   IIRC, wikipedia used to have different constants for some PRNG, maybe some of these, vs. the upstream site; I just copied wikipedia
#include <stdint.h>
uint64_t rol64(uint64_t x, int k)
{
    return (x << k) | (x >> (64 - k));
}

struct xoshiro256ss_state {
    uint64_t s[4];
};

static xoshiro256ss_state rng_state; // init by main
uint64_t xoshiro256ss(struct xoshiro256ss_state *state)
{
    uint64_t *s = state->s;
    uint64_t const result = rol64(s[1] * 5, 7) * 9;
    uint64_t const t = s[1] << 17;

    s[2] ^= s[0];
    s[3] ^= s[1];
    s[1] ^= s[2];
    s[0] ^= s[3];

    s[2] ^= t;
    s[3] = rol64(s[3], 45);

    return result;
}


namespace {
    class MyTimer {
    std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock> start;

public:
    void startCounter() {
        start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    }

    int64_t getCounterNs() {
        return std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(std::chrono::system_clock::now() - start).count();
    }

    int64_t getCounterMs() {
        return std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(std::chrono::system_clock::now() - start).count();
    }

    double getCounterMsPrecise() {
        return std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(std::chrono::system_clock::now() - start).count()
                / 1000000.0;
    }
};
}

template <typename T>
void leb128_encode(uint8_t* data, T value, size_t &idx)
{
  bool more = true;
  bool negative = value < 0;
  constexpr int size = sizeof(value) * 8;

  while (more) {
    uint8_t byte = value & 0x7F;
    value >>= 7;
    if (negative) value |= (~0LL << (size - 7));

    if ((value == 0 && (byte & 0x40) == 0) || (value == -1 && (byte & 0x40) != 0)) {
      more = false;
    } else {
        byte |= 0x80;
    }

    data[idx++] = byte;
  }
}

template <typename T>
void leb128_decode(uint8_t* data, T &value, size_t &idx)
{
  value = 0;
  int shift = 0;
  constexpr int size = sizeof(value) * 8;
  uint8_t byte;

  do {
    byte = data[idx++];
    value |= int64_t(byte & 0x7F) << shift;
    shift += 7;
  } while (byte & 0x80);

  if (shift < size && (byte & 0x40)) {
    value |= (~0LL << shift);
  }
}

int64_t n_msg = 100'000'000;
constexpr int BLK_SIZE = 16;
uint8_t* buffer;

int64_t *original;
int64_t *decoded;
int64_t *dummy_array;

// encode 1 value using variable length encoding,
// storing the result in a flag
void encode(int64_t value, uint8_t &flag, size_t &idx)
{
  bool negative = value < 0;
  value = abs(value);

  uint8_t byte_cnt = 0;
  while (value > 0) {
    buffer[idx] = value & 0xFF; // lowest byte
    idx++;
    value >>= 8;
    byte_cnt++;
  }

  // special cases. Since we only have 3 bits to represent 9 values (0->8),
  // we choose to group case 7-8 together because they're rarest.  
  if (byte_cnt == 7) {
    buffer[idx] = 0;
    idx++;
  } else if (byte_cnt == 8) {
    // since we only have 3 bits, we use 7 to represent 8 bytes
    byte_cnt = 7;
  }

  flag = byte_cnt; // bit 0-2 represent length
  if (negative) flag |= 0b1000; // bit 3 represent sign (1 means negative)  
}

// returns compression ratio
double __attribute__ ((noinline)) encode_all(int type = 0)
{
  if (type == 0) {
    // Soonts version uses the same format as this reference version
    size_t idx = 0;
    // encode in blocks of 16 values
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n_msg; i += 16) {
      size_t flag_idx = idx;
      idx += 8; // first 8 bytes of a block are for sign/length flags
      for (int t = 0; t < BLK_SIZE; t += 2) {
        uint8_t low_flag, high_flag;
        encode(original[i + t], low_flag, idx);
        encode(original[i + t + 1], high_flag, idx);
        buffer[flag_idx + t / 2] = (high_flag << 4) | low_flag;
      }
    }
    return (double(idx) / (n_msg * 8));
  } else if (type == 1) {
    const unsigned char *end = encode_buf_bmi(n_msg, original, buffer);
    return (double(end - buffer) / (n_msg * 8));    
  } else if (type == 2) {
    size_t idx = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n_msg; i++) leb128_encode(buffer, original[i], idx);
    return (double(idx) / (n_msg * 8));
  }

  cout << "encode_all unknown type " << type << std::endl;
  exit(1);
}

template <typename T>
void extract_flag(uint8_t flag, T &low_sign, T &low_length, T &high_sign, T &high_length)
{
  low_sign = flag & 0b1000;
  low_length = flag & 0b0111;
  high_sign = (flag >> 4) & 0b1000;
  high_length = (flag >> 4) & 0b0111;
}

void __attribute__ ((noinline)) decode_original()
{
  static constexpr int64_t mult[] = {
    1, 1LL << 8, 1LL << 16, 1LL << 24, 1LL << 32, 1LL << 40, 1LL << 48, 1LL << 56
  };

  size_t idx = 0, num_idx = 0;
  for (size_t i = 0; i < n_msg; i += 16) {
    // first 8 bytes of a block are flags
    int signs[BLK_SIZE], lens[BLK_SIZE];
    for (int t = 0; t < BLK_SIZE; t += 2) {
      extract_flag(buffer[idx], signs[t], lens[t], signs[t + 1], lens[t + 1]);
      idx++;
    }
    for (int t = 0; t < BLK_SIZE; t++) if (lens[t] == 7) lens[t] = 8; // special case

    // decode BLK_SIZE values  
    for (int t = 0; t < BLK_SIZE; t++) {
      int64_t value = 0;
      for (int i = 0; i < lens[t]; i++) value += mult[i] * buffer[idx + i];
      if (signs[t]) value = -value;
      decoded[num_idx + t] = value;
      idx += lens[t];
    }
    num_idx += BLK_SIZE;
  }
}

void __attribute__ ((noinline)) decode_soonts()
{
  BlockDecoder dec;
  const uint8_t* rsi = buffer;
  int64_t* rdi = decoded;
  for( size_t i = 0; i < n_msg; i += 16 )
  {
      rsi = dec.decode( rdi, rsi );
      rdi += 16;
  }
}

void __attribute__ ((noinline)) decode_aqrit()
{
  decode_buf_bmi(n_msg, buffer, decoded);
}

void __attribute__ ((noinline)) decode_leb()
{
  size_t idx = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < n_msg; i++) {
    leb128_decode(buffer, decoded[i], idx);
  }
}

//------------------
//------------------
//------------------  MAIN

void __attribute__ ((noinline)) gen_data()
{
  for (size_t i = 0; i < n_msg; i++) {
    uint64_t modifier = xoshiro256ss(&rng_state);  // low 32 bits decide magnitude range, high bits decide sign, to avoid correlation with %100 over the full thing.
    if ( uint32_t(modifier) % 100 == 0) {
      original[i] = int64_t(xoshiro256ss(&rng_state)) * 1'000'000'000;
    } else {
      original[i] = xoshiro256ss(&rng_state) % 70'000;
    }
    if ((modifier>>62) == 0)
      original[i] *= -1;
  }
}

void __attribute__ ((noinline)) check(const string &name)
{
  for (size_t i = 0; i < n_msg; i++) if (original[i] != decoded[i]) {
    cout << name << " wrong at " << i << " " << original[i] << " " << decoded[i] << "\n";
    exit(1);
  }
}

int64_t volatile dummy = 42;
constexpr int N_DUMMY = 8'000'000;
void __attribute__ ((noinline)) clear_cache()
{
#if 1
  for (int i = 0; i < N_DUMMY; i++) dummy_array[i] = dummy;
  std::sort(dummy_array, dummy_array + N_DUMMY);
  dummy = dummy_array[rand() % N_DUMMY];
#else
    asm("" ::: "memory");
#endif
}

using FuncPtr = void (*)();
int64_t __attribute__ ((noinline)) test(FuncPtr func, const string &name)
{
  clear_cache();
  MyTimer timer;
  timer.startCounter();
  func();
  int64_t cost = timer.getCounterNs();
  check(name);
  return cost;
}

void printTableRow(const std::vector<std::string>& columns, int columnWidth) {
    for (const std::string& column : columns) {
        std::cout << std::left << std::setw(columnWidth) << column << " | ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
  // srand(time(NULL));
  rng_state.s[0] = time(nullptr);  // other elements left zero.  This is terrible but sufficient for our purposes

  MyTimer timer;
  buffer = new uint8_t[n_msg * 10];
  original = new int64_t[n_msg];
  decoded = new int64_t[n_msg];
  dummy_array = new int64_t[N_DUMMY]; // enough to flush cache
  
  memset(buffer, 0, n_msg * 10);
  memset(original, 0, n_msg * 8);
  memset(decoded, 0, n_msg * 8);
  memset(dummy_array, 0, N_DUMMY * 8);

  int n_test = 10;
  constexpr int L = 4;
  string names[L] = {"original", "soonts", "aqrit", "leb"};
  int64_t total_costs[L] = {0, 0, 0, 0};

  for (int t = 0; t < n_test; t++) {    
    gen_data();
    double ratio_original = encode_all(0);
    int64_t costs[L];

    costs[0] = test(decode_original, names[0]);
    costs[1] = test(decode_soonts, names[1]);

    double ratio_aqrit = encode_all(1);
    costs[2] = test(decode_aqrit, names[2]);

    double ratio_leb = encode_all(2);
    costs[3] = test(decode_leb, names[3]);
    
    if (t == 0) {
      cout << "Compression ratios: " << ratio_original << " " << ratio_aqrit << " " << ratio_leb << "\n";
    }

    cout << t << ": ";
    for (int i = 0; i < L; i++) {
      cout << (double(costs[i]) / 1'000'000) << " ";
      total_costs[i] += costs[i];
    }
    cout << "\n";
  }

  vector<string> headers = {"name", "cost (ms)", "cost/int64 (ns)", "cost/byte (ns)"};
  printTableRow(headers, 15);
  for (int i = 0; i < L; i++) {    
    double average_cost_ms = double(total_costs[i]) / n_test / 1'000'000;
    double cost_int64 = double(total_costs[i]) / (n_msg * n_test);
    double cost_byte = cost_int64 / 8;
    
    vector<string> row;
    row.push_back(names[i]);
    row.push_back(to_string(average_cost_ms));
    row.push_back(to_string(cost_int64));
    row.push_back(to_string(cost_byte));
    printTableRow(row, 15);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

**Edit:** I've just found out that someone discovered [pretty much the same encode/decode format](https://github.com/lemire/streamvbyte/tree/master#format-specification) (but for int32) in 2017. What a fun coincidence, where 2 people independently "invent" the same thing at 2 different times :D

2nd version of Soonts' answer (`func`, `inl func`, `vpgather`) code [here](https://gist.github.com/Const-me/e897e4565b2c6a2e69d8b5d2c1457730). It looks cleaner, and doesn't read past the end of input buffer, but measurably slower, so I'm keeping the 1st version.

- `func`: this version doesn't require a decoder object. `force_inline = 0, use_gather = 0`
- `inl func`: `force_inline = 1, use_gather = 0`
- `vpgather`: `force_inline = 0, use_gather = 1`

Compile command: `g++ -o main test.cpp -std=c+=17 -O3 -mavx2 -mlzcnt -march=native`

Benchmark on . `-march=native` gives measurable performance boost (~8% best case)

Time to decompress `10^8` int64, averaged over 10 runs:

```
// AMD EPYC 75F3 (Zen 3 x86-64), 2950MHz
Compression ratios: 0.327437 0.369956
0: 447.651 65.0414 110.171 
1: 442.853 64.5952 105.635 
2: 434.715 64.1977 108.984 
3: 430.09 63.0572 104.074 
4: 424.451 64.6397 103.604 
5: 436.631 65.0076 104.04 
6: 429.59 64.1896 102.936 
7: 434.184 64.0522 104.035 
8: 430.223 69.3877 105.922 
9: 420.659 63.7519 105.563
// AMD EPYC 75F3 -march=native
name            | cost (ms)       | cost/int64 (ns) | cost/byte (ns)  | 
original        | 433.104635      | 4.331046        | 0.541381        | 
soonts          | 64.792034       | 0.647920        | 0.080990        | 
aqrit           | 105.496544      | 1.054965        | 0.131871        |
leb             | 438.236469      | 4.382365        | 0.547796        |
soonts (func)   | 68.403465       | 0.684035        | 0.085504        | 
soon (inl func) | 71.202335       | 0.712023        | 0.089003        |
soon (vpgather) | 78.308508       | 0.783085        | 0.097886        |

// AMD EPYC 75F3 without -march=native
name            | cost (ms)       | cost/int64 (ns) | cost/byte (ns)  | 
original        | 424.631426      | 4.246314        | 0.530789        | 
soonts          | 69.623498       | 0.696235        | 0.087029        | 
aqrit           | 109.895916      | 1.098959        | 0.137370        | 

// Intel(R) Xeon(R) Gold 6252N CPU (supposedly 2.3 GHz, I can't change/lock frequency on this borrowed machine)
name            | cost (ms)       | cost/int64 (ns) | cost/byte (ns)  | 
original        | 549.280441      | 5.492804        | 0.686601        | 
soonts          | 118.401718      | 1.184017        | 0.148002        | 
aqrit           | 151.811314      | 1.518113        | 0.189764        |
soon (func)     | 122.440794      | 1.224408        | 0.153051        |
soon (inl func) | 120.559447      | 1.205594        | 0.150699        |
soon (vpgather) | 115.704298      | 1.157043        | 0.144630        |
aqrit           | 151.811314      | 1.518113        | 0.189764        |
```

Comment: Have you looked at varint?  With BMI2 `pext` it can be pretty fast on Zen 3 or later, or Intel Haswell and later.  (Zen 2 and earlier support BMI2, but have a disastrously slow microcoded `pdep` / `pext`.)  Also AVX-512 might help with varint decoding, if `vpcompressb` is available and fast.  [Why is varint an efficient data representation?](//stackoverflow.com/q/24614553)

Comment: I found a link related to `varint` and it's the same as `LEB128`. Is there another method with the same name? https://techoverflow.net/2013/01/25/efficiently-encoding-variable-length-integers-in-cc/

Comment: I have some work-in-progress varint encode/decode code using BMI2 or AVX-512 VBMI which I never got around to posting on [Decompress varint64 stream into the qword elements of an __m256i with AVX2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68102021).  In case it's useful to anyone: https://godbolt.org/z/76bcanMTG .  The functions are heavily commented, but I forget which I've tested.

Comment: Oh, yeah I think LEB128 looks the same as `varint`, using the MSB to signal whether there's another byte.  Your scheme might well be more SIMD-friendly, or at least amenable to running fast on CPUs like Zen 2 and earlier without fast `pext` or AVX-512VBMI.  Fast `bzhi` probably helps, doing a 64-bit load and using the `length` field to decide how many upper bits to zero, as well as what pointer-increment to use.  Hrm, that means load-use latency is part of the loop-carried data dependency critical path, same problem I had with optimizing varint decode, especially with scalar.

Comment: LEB128 presumably stands for Little-Endian Base-128, the number of useful bits in each "digit" (byte).  It's an arbitrary-precision format, unlike a scheme using a fixed-width count of how many more bytes.  If you only need to encode numbers that fit in an int64_t, that limitation is fine, although it's a bit less dense than LEB128 where you might only have 1 to 2 bits signalling length for small numbers, rather than an extra whole byte for just length and sign.  Speed/space tradeoffs are not rare in this type of thing.

Comment: Right now it uses exactly 4 bits per number (1 for sign, 3 for length). If I use variable number of bits to represent flag, it'll be (probably) slower to decode while saving not much space (since you need to fit them in a byte anyway), so I haven't bother trying. Also fixed 4 bits means the flag will always be stored inside 1 byte, instead of possibly between 2 bytes

Comment: You can't make any other use of the space inside that first byte, so you're effectively using all 7 bits for length.  e.g. a 5-byte value has 40 total bits.  There are 32 (+ 1 sign) value bits, and 7 bits used only for length stuff.  v.s. a 5-byte varint has 35 value bits, able to encode integers up to `2^35 - 1` in 5 bytes, vs. yours only `+- 2^32 - 1`.  Both have byte granularity so a value that's only slightly too big needs 8 more bits of total storage space.  But the thresholds are different for the two encodings.

Comment: Plotting bytes used against integer value, varint is probably smaller or equal for all `x < 2^32`, but maybe larger near the largest 64-bit integers.  (Which again is fine; saving a bit less space can be fine if decompression is significantly faster, which might be the case on Zen 2.)

Comment: Regarding "Special note: most values has length <= 2 bytes": What does "most" mean in this case? Would it be sufficient to handle the `<=2` case with super efficient code and fall back to generic code otherwise? Do you also "most of the time" have 4 consecutive values <=2 bytes?

Comment: Your code immediately resulted in a segmentation fault. The `n_msg` in `memset(dummy_array, 0, n_msg * 8)` needs to be `N_DUMMY`.

Comment: @MarkAdler fixed. Thanks!

Comment: @chtz yes, most of the time 4 consecutive values can be represented by <= 7 bytes. I actually handle cases where `sum(lens[0:4) <= 8` separately in my actual code. If you look at `gen_data`, 99% of values are `< 70000`, so ~92.7% of the data can be represented by 2 bytes or less, 6.3% by 3 bytes, and 1% by 8 bytes. I've added some extra notes

Comment: Oh, I see, your format works in blocks so the signs are grouped together, something the text didn't mention.  Not like varint where you need to finish length decoding for each number before you can load anything for the next, unless you find some parallel decoding tricks.  That definitely makes it more SIMD-friendly.  Having two separate arrays, of sign/lengths and data, could help ILP since we could be starting on the next batch of signs without a data-dependency on the last prefix sum.  You'd still need them to get gather indices, though.  (Or shuffle-control vectors for AVX-512 `vpermb`)

Comment: And I'd earlier missed that you were packing two sign+len flags into a byte.  So you aren't leaving bits unused in the flag bytes.

Comment: If this was in different files I'd suggest `-flto` to enable Link Time Optimization, but since it seems to all be in one file then that won't make a difference..

Comment: `srand(time(NULL));` - horrible seed for a horrible random number generator. I'd advice watching [rand() Considered Harmful](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LDPMpc-ENqY) (ohh and don't use `NULL` in modern C++, use `nullptr`).

Comment: @JesperJuhl it's just for a short demo so `srand` is fine. For serious randomness I would use mt19937

Comment: The benchmark framework spends 75% of its user-space time inside `random` in libc (85% with the sort commented out), most of that on locking / unlocking around access to the shared global seed (it's not per-thread).  (64% random locking, 9% real work inside random_r).  So it makes benchmarking painfully slow when it doesn't need to be, vs. something fast and good like Xorshift+ or xoroshiro (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xorshift).  The quality of randomness should be fine for this purpose, though, @JesperJuhl, especially on GNU/Linux where `rand()` isn't *total* garbage IIRC.

Comment: vs. only 25% of the time spent in `gen_data` with xoshiro256\*\*, without the cache clearing sort.  (Or 42% in `gen_data` with aqrit's version of encode/decode.)  As a 64-bit PRNG, I guess it might produce bigger numbers more often in the `* 1Bn` case?  I didn't look at the distribution.  Anyway, the test program takes 7 seconds vs. 50 to 55.  https://godbolt.org/z/rdG3Eqcxh

Comment: Thank you, I will update the benchmark code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It’s relatively tricky, but still possible to vectorize your decoder. Here’s an implementation which on my computer with AMD Zen3 CPU outperforms your reference version by the factor of 2.8.

```
#include <immintrin.h>
#include <stdint.h>

// Exclusive prefix sum of unsigned bytes
// When the sum of all bytes exceeds 0xFF, the output is garbage
// Which is fine here because our bytes are in [0..8] interval
inline __m128i exclusivePrefixSum( const __m128i src, size_t& sum )
{
    __m128i v = src;
    // https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prefix_sum#/media/File:Hillis-Steele_Prefix_Sum.svg
    v = _mm_add_epi8( v, _mm_slli_si128( v, 1 ) );
    v = _mm_add_epi8( v, _mm_slli_si128( v, 2 ) );
    v = _mm_add_epi8( v, _mm_slli_si128( v, 4 ) );
    v = _mm_add_epi8( v, _mm_slli_si128( v, 8 ) );

    // So far we have computed inclusive prefix sum
    // Keep the last byte which is total sum of bytes in the vector
    uint16_t tmp = _mm_extract_epi16( v, 7 );
    tmp >>= 8;
    sum = tmp;

    // Subtract original numbers to make exclusive sum = byte offsets to load
    return _mm_sub_epi8( v, src );
}

// Load 4 uint64 numbers from ( rsi + offsets[ i ] ), keep the lowest bits[ i ] bits in the numbers
inline __m256i loadAndMask( const uint8_t* rsi, uint32_t offsets, __m128i bits )
{
    // Load 4 uint64_t numbers from the correct locations, without AVX2 gathers
    const int64_t* s0 = (const int64_t*)( rsi + (uint8_t)offsets );
    const int64_t* s1 = (const int64_t*)( rsi + (uint8_t)( offsets >> 8 ) );
    const int64_t* s2 = (const int64_t*)( rsi + (uint8_t)( offsets >> 16 ) );
    const int64_t* s3 = (const int64_t*)( rsi + ( offsets >> 24 ) );
    __m256i r = _mm256_setr_epi64x( *s0, *s1, *s2, *s3 );

    // Mask away the higher pieces in the loaded numbers
    __m256i shift = _mm256_cvtepu8_epi64( bits );
    const __m256i ones = _mm256_set1_epi32( -1 );
    __m256i mask = _mm256_sllv_epi64( ones, shift );
    return _mm256_andnot_si256( mask, r );
}

inline __m256i applySigns( __m256i v, __m128i signs )
{
    // Sign extend the masks from bytes to int64
    __m256i mask = _mm256_cvtepi8_epi64( signs );
    // Conditionally negate the numbers
    __m256i neg = _mm256_sub_epi64( _mm256_setzero_si256(), v );
    return _mm256_blendv_epi8( v, neg, mask );
}

class BlockDecoder
{
    // Load offsets, in bytes
    __m128i offsetBytes;
    // Payload bits per element, the bytes are in [ 0 .. 64 ] interval
    __m128i payloadBits;
    // 16 bytes with the 0x80 bit set when the corresponding input was negative; the rest of the bits are unused
    __m128i signs;
    // Count of payload bytes in the complete block
    size_t payloadBytes;

    // Decode the block header
    inline void loadHeader( const uint8_t* rsi )
    {
        // Load 8 bytes, and zero extend them into uint16_t
        const __m128i v = _mm_cvtepu8_epi16( _mm_loadu_si64( rsi ) );

        // Unpack lengths
        const __m128i seven = _mm_set1_epi8( 7 );
        const __m128i l4 = _mm_slli_epi16( v, 4 );
        __m128i lengths = _mm_or_si128( v, l4 );
        lengths = _mm_and_si128( lengths, seven );
        // Transform 7 into 8
        __m128i tmp = _mm_cmpeq_epi8( lengths, seven );
        lengths = _mm_sub_epi8( lengths, tmp );

        // Byte offsets to load 16 numbers, and count of payload bytes in the complete block
        offsetBytes = exclusivePrefixSum( lengths, payloadBytes );
        // Count of payload bits in the loaded numbers, lengths * 8
        payloadBits = _mm_slli_epi16( lengths, 3 );
        // Signs vector, we only use the highest 0x80 bit in these bytes
        signs = _mm_or_si128( _mm_slli_epi16( v, 8 ), l4 );
    }

    // Decode and store 4 numbers
    template<int slice>
    inline void decodeSlice( int64_t* rdi, const uint8_t* payload ) const
    {
        uint32_t off;
        __m128i bits, s;
        if constexpr( slice != 0 )
        {
            off = (uint32_t)_mm_extract_epi32( offsetBytes, slice );
            constexpr int imm = _MM_SHUFFLE( slice, slice, slice, slice );
            bits = _mm_shuffle_epi32( payloadBits, imm );
            s = _mm_shuffle_epi32( signs, imm );
        }
        else
        {
            off = (uint32_t)_mm_cvtsi128_si32( offsetBytes );
            // For the first slice of the block, the 4 lowest bytes are in the correct locations already
            bits = payloadBits;
            s = signs;
        }

        __m256i v = loadAndMask( payload, off, bits );
        v = applySigns( v, s );
        _mm256_storeu_si256( ( __m256i* )rdi, v );
    }

public:

    // Decode and store a block of 16 numbers, return pointer to the next block
    const uint8_t* decode( int64_t* rdi, const uint8_t* rsi )
    {
        loadHeader( rsi );
        rsi += 8;

        decodeSlice<0>( rdi, rsi );
        decodeSlice<1>( rdi + 4, rsi );
        decodeSlice<2>( rdi + 8, rsi );
        decodeSlice<3>( rdi + 12, rsi );

        return rsi + payloadBytes;
    }
};
```

I’ve tested the code very little, and it could be possible to improve the performance further.

As you see, the implementation requires AVX2, and is branchless.

Usage example:

```
BlockDecoder dec;
const uint8_t* rsi = buffer;
int64_t* rdi = decoded;
for( size_t i = 0; i < n_msg; i += 16 )
{
    rsi = dec.decode( rdi, rsi );
    rdi += 16;
}
```

**NB!** Typically, when the last number in the stream doesn’t use the maximum 8 bytes, the implementation loads a few bytes past the end of the encoded buffer. You can pad your compressed data, or implement a special case to decode the final block of the stream, or adjust the encoder to always emit 8 bytes for the final number of the final block.

P.S. The initial version used `_mm256_i32gather_epi64` instruction to load four int64 numbers from memory, using a base pointer + four byte offsets from another vector. However, on AMD CPUs it was slightly slower than 4 scalar loads. If you target Intel, might be better to use the initial version, see edit history.

Comment: Note that `vpgatherdq` sped up from 32 uops / 9c throughput in the OP's Zen 2 to 23 uops / 4c throughput in your Zen 3.  (https://uops.info/).  It's much better on Intel, especially Skylake and later, only 4 front-end uops, and 4c to 2c throughput (SKL through Alder Lake).

Comment: The reference encoder / decoder look pretty inefficient, working 1 byte at a time instead of using `memcpy` to load 8 bytes and `lzcnt(abs(x)) >> 3` to find how many bytes it needs.  Or `memcpy` and `bzhi` to load and zero-extend a variable number of bytes.  IDK if that would get close to a 2.7x speedup over the reference implementation for data where small numbers are common, though, so the SIMD gather version might still be a win.

Comment: @PeterCordes Good point on `vpgatherdq` I found that on my computer, 4 scalar loads are slightly faster than a single gather, see the update.

Comment: I benchmarked aqrit's optimized scalar version on my 3.9GHz Skylake CPU with GCC13.2 and Clang 16.  Also yours and the reference version: https://godbolt.org/z/WP386Ec7f with `-DSOONTS_VERSION` or `-DAQRIT_VERSION` or neither.  aqrit: 138 ms for decoding a buffer with GCC or clang, vs. your AVX2 non-gather decode: 91 ms, vs. the reference implementation 382 ms (clang) or 535 ms (GCC).  So efficient scalar is 3.9x faster with GCC, or 2.7x faster with clang `-O3 -march=skylake -mbranches-within-32B-boundaries`.

Comment: So on Skylake there's still a 1.5x speedup from AVX2 vs. an *efficient* scalar version, vs. a 4.2x or 5.9x speedup over the reference implementation.  I haven't tried your gather version.  (This is with the OP's slow cache flush between runs, since apparently they care about the cold-L3 case.  Removing that and using just `asm("" ::: "memory")` only speeds up the timed region (decode) by a tiny amount for aqrit, like to 135 ms, or not at all for your, like 92 ms up from 91.)

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/rdG3Eqcxh has this and aqrit's versions, and a much faster PRNG (xoshiro256\*\*(, and turns cache_clear into mostly a no-op.  (vs. my earlier link, bugfixed the compression ratio calculation for aqrit's encoder, it was previously printing 0 since I wasn't returning the end-pointer, which is necessary information for the callee to get.)  Typical compression ratio 0.3670 for aqrit vs. 0.3274 for the reference format (which Soonts's decoder works on), with this random distribution.

Comment: I tested on a server CPU (EPYC 75F3), and the difference is 6.1x, that's huge. I will test on more CPUs later if possible

Comment: @HuyLe Please test that version: https://gist.github.com/Const-me/e897e4565b2c6a2e69d8b5d2c1457730 It uses the right shift approach from the other answer, no longer loads from past the end of the encoded buffer. Also refactored away the C++ class. And there’s a macro to use AVX2 gather instructions.

Comment: @Soonts for some reason, the new version is slower. Force inline `decodeBlock` also makes it slower. `USE_GATHER` is much slower as you expected, I'll test on Intel later. I'm keeping the original version in the for now, since it's still fastest. Also loading beyond the encoded buffer is not a problem, we over-allocate memory anyway.

Comment: @Soonts I tested on 1 Intel CPU, and `vpgather` is faster than scalar load on that one. It's an older CPU at lower clock though, so total time is much slower compared to AMD 75F3.

Comment: @HuyLe Gathers are expected, but the performance decrease is a mystery. I know two possible explanations (1) your GCC screwed up code generation for my non-OO version, but did a good job for the class (2) The decrease is due to the latency of `_mm256_srlv_epi64`. In OO version that shift is independent on the value only depends on the header, the instruction will run in parallel with the loads. And then my VC++ screwed up code generation for my OO version, but did a good job for the second one so on my Windows computer the second version is slightly faster.

Comment: `const int64_t* s0 = (const int64_t*)( rsi + (uint8_t)offsets );` isn't this undefined behavior? `-fsanitize=undefined` says it is. I have to `int64_t s0; memcpy(&s0, rsi + (uint8_t)offsets, sizeof(int64_t));` instead

Comment: @HuyLe The language standard says it is undefined because some platforms require alignment and crash with unaligned scalar loads. However, the code in question requires AVX2, i.e. only builds for modern AMD64 processors which don’t have any issues with unaligned 8-byte loads. I usually ignore such warnings in the code like that. `memcpy` is IMO less readable. And at least here in vc++, it slows down debug builds by a huge factor, because unoptimized builds compile `memcpy` into function calls.

Comment: I ran both version and there's no speed difference between using `memcpy` and reinterpreting `char*` as `int64_t*`. I'll use the `memcpy` version because it's "more correct"

Comment: @HuyLe Yeah, the optimized release builds deliver equivalent code. The performance only suffers for unoptimized builds. VC++ in debug configuration emits function call for each `memcpy`. GCC with `-O0` doesn’t but still moves data too much: source memory -> scalar register -> stack memory -> scalar register -> output vector register. The good code is source memory -> output vector register, using `vmovq` and `vpinsrq` instructions with memory operands to load, and one `vinserti128` to assemble the complete vector from two pieces.

Comment: @HuyLe: Re: gather performance, keep in mind that most Intel cloud servers will have Downfall mitigation enabled, which destroys gather performance so much that it has a big effect on *overall* speed of some workloads that use it.  I haven't seen microbenchmarks of gather instructions with it applied.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Downfall_(security_vulnerability)

Comment: @Soonts: Alignment UB is a bad habit and can break in practice even when compiling for x86-64.  See [Why does unaligned access to mmap'ed memory sometimes segfault on AMD64?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47510783) / https://trust-in-soft.com/blog/2020/04/06/gcc-always-assumes-aligned-pointers/ / https://pzemtsov.github.io/2016/11/06/bug-story-alignment-on-x86.html for multiple different instances of people being bitten by this.  Use `memcpy` or `typedef uint64_t unaligned_u64 __attribute__((aligned(1),may_alias))`.

Answer (score 2):

A scalar implementation could be branchless, for the most part.

Padding out the control bits with the sign bits probably cost bits in the long run.
Instead, here all the control bits are packed at the start of the stream (similar to streamvbyte).

Variable sign-extension is used because it is cheaper than zigzag for bytewise scalar implmentations.

Proof of concept assumes:

- Fast unaligned memory access (and memcpy optimizes away)
- Little endian memory order
- Arithmetic right shifts

```
#include <cstddef>  // size_t
#include <cstdint> // uint64_t, int64_t
#include <immintrin.h> // lzcnt intrinsic
#include <cstring> // memcpy

unsigned char* encode(size_t n, const int64_t* src, unsigned char* dst) {
    unsigned char* key_ptr = dst;
    size_t num_chunks = n >> 3;
    unsigned char* data_ptr = &dst[(num_chunks * 3) + ((((n & 0x7) * 3) + 7) >> 3)];
    while (num_chunks--) {
        uint64_t key = 0;
        for (size_t i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            uint64_t v = (uint64_t)*src++;
            memcpy(data_ptr, &v, sizeof(v)); // assumes little endian

            v = (v + v) ^ v; // clear redundant sign bits (and trash everything else)
            v = (v << 8) | v; // combine lengths of 7 and 8
            v = (_lzcnt_u64(v | 1) ^ 63) >> 3; // use BSR on intel... 
            data_ptr += v + ((v + 1) >> 3); // key of 7 is length of 8
            key |= v << (i * 3);
        }
        memcpy(key_ptr, &key, 3); // assumes little endian
        key_ptr += 3;
    }
    // TODO: tail loop...
    
    return dst;
}
    
void decode(size_t n, const unsigned char* src, int64_t* dst) {
    const unsigned char* key_ptr = src;
    size_t num_chunks = n >> 3;
    const unsigned char* data_ptr = &src[(num_chunks * 3) + ((((n & 0x7) * 3) + 7) >> 3)];
    if (n >= 19) { // if has at least 8 bytes of padding before data_ptr
        data_ptr -= sizeof(uint64_t); // left aligned the truncated val in register (little endian) 
        while (num_chunks--) {
            unsigned keys;
            memcpy(&keys, key_ptr, 3);
            key_ptr += 3;
            for (size_t i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
                uint64_t v;
                size_t k = keys & 0x07;
                size_t len = k + ((k + 1) >> 3); // k==7 is len=8
                uint64_t mask = (uint64_t)0 - ((k + 7) >> 3); // k ? -1 : 0
                size_t shift = (64 - (len * 8)) & (size_t)mask; 

                keys >>= 3;     
                data_ptr += len; 
                memcpy(&v, data_ptr, sizeof(v));
                v &= mask;
                *dst++ = (int64_t)v >> shift;
            }
        }
        data_ptr += sizeof(uint64_t);
    }

    // TODO: tail loop...
}
```

Comment: `memcpy(&keys, key_ptr, 4);` is probably more efficient than a 3-byte memcpy, especially one that leaves the upper byte uninitialized.  Since the keys are at the start followed by data in the same buffer, we know for a fact it's safe to just do a dword load = 4-byte memcpy.  Also, a 64-bit shift count of `64 - c` is equivalent to `v >> (-c & 63)`, and `neg` is slightly cheaper than materializing a `64` somewhere to subtract from on x86; x86 shifts mask the count for free.  (ARM has `rsb` reverse-subtract from an immediate, but saturates shift counts instead of masking, so maybe worse there.)

Comment: With the OP's benchmark, decode of a whole buffer runs in 258 ms on my 3.9GHz Skylake with GCC13.2.  Or with Clang 16.0, in 138 ms.  (vs. 535 ms GCC or 381 ms Clang for the OP's byte-at-a-time reference implementation that avoids bit-scan).  Changing the `memcpy` to a 4-byte load speeds GCC up to match clang: https://godbolt.org/z/G684z56Mj All with `-O3 -march=skylake -Wa,-mbranches-within-32B-boundaries`.  (Or without the leading `-Wa,` for clang).

Comment: You could use C++20 `std::countl_zero` in place of `_lzcnt_u64`, but the lzcnt intrinsic rules out the mistake of compiling without `-m` options and getting a slower-on-AMD `bsr`, or a slower-on-Intel `sar` instead of `sarx`.  (Nice trick of misaligning the load so the sign bit is already at the top, not needing a left shift first).

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/rdG3Eqcxh has this and Soonts's versions, and a much faster PRNG, and turns cache_clear into mostly a no-op.  (vs. my earlier link, bugfixed the compression ratio calculation for your encoder, it was previously printing 0 since I wasn't returning the end-pointer, which is necessary information for the callee to get.)  Typical compression ratio 0.3670 vs. 0.3274 for the reference format (which Soonts's decoder works on), with this random distribution (or for the original using `rand()`, so apparently I didn't break anything with it.)

Comment: I wonder if the test-case's specific choice of `%70'000` and `* 1 Bn` lead to sizes that often need an extra byte if the sign bit isn't stored separately?  I'd have expected your encoding to compress better on average, to a smaller fraction of the input size.  I didn't try alternate distributions, like `log2(abs(n))` uniformly distributed.

Comment: @PeterCordes Yes, the number `70000` and 1% `* 1 Bn` are intentional and were found using real data in my use case. That's why I went with storing sign bit + unsigned absolute value, instead of using signed number encode/decode