# Convert Variable Width Bitstream (2-bit or 4-bit symbols) into Fixed Width

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation, simd, neon, avx2

I'm converting a variable width set of bit packed instructions (2 bits per symbol, but some symbols take two consecutive codepoints).

I'd like to convert this into a 3-bit fixed width code (there are 6 possible symbols) so I can do lookup table decoding.

Is there an efficient way to do this with SIMD? Most options seem to operate at the byte level.

Comment: Semi-related: [C++ how to speed up (with x86 SIMD) batch variable length integer encoding / decoding (runnable benchmark)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77373402) might have some inspiration (along with my comment about AVX2 varint encode/decode).  But that's dealing with values wider than a byte so a different kind of strategy might be warranted here.

Comment: What SIMD ISAs do you care about?  Do you have AArch64 SVE for vector pdep / pext?  Or Ice Lake and later AVX-512VBMI for `vpmultishiftqb`?  Is your code self-synchronizing, so if you extracted every 2-bit-aligned window of 4 bits to a separate byte, you could tell which ones were were invalid (because they were actually the last 2 bits of one symbol and the first 2 bits of the next?) If so, you could probably do some broadcast + shift and `vpshufb` to look at the low 4 bits to map them to symbols or invalid, but then you'd need to left-pack to discard invalid. Like with AVX-512 `vpcompressb`.

Comment: Cheap GCS instances so probably no higher than AVX2? Ideally NEON would be handled as well. The code is not self synchronizing. It's a compression format :-/. I'm toying with ways to improve the decoder. There's a slightly more detailed description here if you're interested: https://github.com/seung-lab/crackle?tab=readme-ov-file#boundary-structure-crack-code

Comment: Ice Lake is several years old at this point, I'd guess it's not that hard or much more expensive to spec those instances for AVX-512VBMI.   You don't need the latest Sapphire Rapids.   NEON has bit shift-and-insert and widening ops that can be used to unpack, but IIRC it's only SVE that has per-element bit-deposit / bit-extract which may be useful here.  (Like x86 scalar `pdep` / `pext`, which perhaps we can make masks for, although something using XMM or YMM shuffles is probably even better.)

Comment: Can't you make the codes at least somewhat self-synchronizing?  Like the 2-bit pattern that signals the presence of another 2 bits is not used as the second 2-bit chunk.  That still leaves 6 symbols rather than 3 + 4 = 7.  With that design, for a given 2-bit chunk, you can look at it and the *previous* 2 bits to tell whether it's the start of a new symbol or not, I think.  That's important for decoding in parallel; unlike x86 machine code, decoding from one start point can't stay out-of-sync for more than 1 symbol, so you don't need a serial dependency or a lookup-table of shuffles.

Comment: With a code like that, I think AVX-512VBMI (Ice Lake or Zen 4) can decode 64 bits (up to 32 symbols) in a handful of instructions with a `__m256i` vector, or 128 bits (up to 64 symbols) in a couple more instructions with one `__m512i` vector.  Start with `vpbroadcastq` (set1_epi64), then `vpmultishiftqb` to extract 8 bits (we only care about the low 4) into each byte element.  (If there was a symbol spanning the 64-bit boundary, it's trickier...)  `vpandq` and `vpcmpb` + `kshift` to get a mask of invalid symbols: ones whose preceding 2 bits were the start-of-4-bit code.  Then `vpcompressb`.

Comment: Or maybe `vpmultishiftqb` to grab 6-bit fields, including the preceding 2 bits, so we don't need a `kshift`.  `vpermb zmm` can use a 6-bit shuffle index so we can avoid a vector shift + mask like we'd need for `vpshufb` to actually map the 4-bit codes to arbitrary byte values (before or after packing, probably before so the lookup can run in parallel with mask setup.)

Comment: I wonder... it might be possible to change the code like that. In the context of the problem (tracing cracks between pixels) it's only possible to make 3 moves (straight, left, right). If the 4th entry was a special code, that might simplify things. I'll have to think about that. Right now the code is up,down,left,right with impossible combos of directions encoding the branching and terminal symbols.

Comment: @SapphireSun Please make your question self-contained (if you only have 6 decoded symbols, you can easily describe your entire code) -- don't hide relevant information in external links in the comments. Also write what you tried so far (at least some non-vectorized function). It's not like you joined SO this week ...

Comment: You're right, I should describe the problem a bit better. Will do so soon.