# std::atomic_ref required alignment

Tags: c++, c++20, atomic, memory-alignment, stdatomic

According to [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic_ref/required_alignment), hardware could require that an object to be referenced by an `atomic_ref<T>` have stricter alignment than other `T` objects, and whether operations on an `atomic_ref` are lock-free can depend on the alignment of the referenced object.

Why is it only necessary that objects to be referenced by an `atomic_ref` have proper alignment, whereas `std::atomic` does not seem to impose this requirement?

Comment: Where did you get that std::atomic does not have this requirement? Because it does!

Comment: What if `int` is unaligned (as could be on Intel, although a silly idea) but `std::atomic<int>` needs `sizeof(int)`  alignment? Not possible?

Comment: @curiousguy: The alignment requirement / guarantee (`alignof(int)`) is set by the compiler / ABI (the C++ implementation), not just the target ISA.  All mainstream C++ compilers use `alignof(int) == 4`, so it's UB to deref (or technically even to create) an unaligned `int*`.  See [Why does unaligned access to mmap'ed memory sometimes segfault on AMD64?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47510783) - it can actually break even when compiling for x86-64, despite the fact that accesses narrower than 16 bytes wide don't need alignment in asm for that target.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`std::atomic` allocates the `T` object as a class member, so its internals can apply sufficient alignment.

It's not well-defined to point an `atomic<T>*` at an existing `T` object, although in many implementations it happens to work.  That's the problem that `std::atomic_ref<T>` is designed to solve; doing atomic accesses on a plain `T` object that exists separately and which you might do some non-atomic accesses to in other phases of your program.  Before C++20, the standard didn't provide a way to do that at all; that's why a programmer-visible requirement to align a plain `T` object yourself is new in C++20 if you want to use `atomic_ref`, like

```
alignas(std::atomic_ref<T>::required_alignment) T foo;
```

`std::atomic_ref<T>::required_alignment` will be equal to `alignof(std::atomic<T>)`, even if `alignof(T)` is lower.  At least in normal implementations.

---

Without `std::atomic_ref`, you could of course use the compiler-specific extensions like GNU C `__atomic` builtins on plain objects.

That's how `std::atomic<T>` and `std::atomic_ref<T>` are implemented in GCC / clang headers, rather than direct support in the compiler proper like with the C11 `_Atomic` keyword.  (Which has to do its own over-alignment of things it's applied to.  There was [GCC bug <s>65146</s>](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=65146)  for a while where `_Atomic` didn't force the alignment of `int64_t` even on 32-bit targets where it only had 4-byte alignment such as x86; it worked outside structs because GCC chose to align `int64_t` for performance, but was not actually atomic inside structs.  G++'s `std::atomic<>` had fixed that bug earlier, in the `<atomic>` header, but C `_Atomic` is internal to the compiler.)