# How to test how does a RISC-V implementation process misaligned data access?

Tags: linux, unix, cpu, memory-alignment, riscv

I see some words on riscv-spec-20191213:
Loads and stores where the effective address is not naturally aligned to the referenced datatype (i.e., on a four-byte boundary for 32-bit accesses, and a two-byte boundary for 16-bit accesses) have behavior dependent on the EEI.

In other words, EEIs can determine how they process misaligned data access. My question is can we examine the EEIs' behaviours when they meet the misaligned data access?

I have read some materials and test if a SIGBUS signal was raised when misaligned data access using code snippets below.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <error.h>
#include <errno.h>

void sigbus_handler(int signum) {
    printf("A SIGBUS\n");
}

void init_sigbus() {
    if (signal(SIGBUS, sigbus_handler) == SIG_ERR) {
        perror("Error setting signal handler");
    }
}

int main() {
    long long a = 0x1010101010101010LL;
    long long *pa = &a;
    int *pia = (int *)pa;

    /* this make sure the pointer pia is 0x.....100 */
    pia += 1;

    init_sigbus();

    /* mda */
    long long b = *(long long*)pia;

    return 0;
}
```

The result is that no SIGBUSs were raised when mda.

Thank you all for your attention!

**Edit1:**

Below is the screenshot of gdb:
[image]

The address of `pia` is misaligned.

Comment: You should look at the assembly code produced for that; modern compilers can remove a lot of address taken and indirection especially involving local variables.

Comment: Thank you. The runtime value of pia is 0x3ffffff224. So I think the b = *pia is a mda. Is it right? I have posted the picture to the question.

Comment: `*(long long*)pia;` is undefined behaviour for multiple reasons: dereferencing a misaligned `long long*`, and also reading past the end of the 8-byte object `a`.  At least use a char array or maybe `malloc` to get an anonymous buffer, and `volatile` or something to hide the misalignment from the compiler, and maybe make the unaligned access `volatile` as well, e.g. `int *volatile p = something` and `*(volatile uint64_t*)(p+1)`.

Comment: And preferably `typedef uint64_t unaligned_u64 __attribute__((aligned(1),may_alias))` in GNU C.  ([Why does unaligned access to mmap'ed memory sometimes segfault on AMD64?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47510783)).  Unless that typedef makes GCC use multiple instructions instead of an unaligned doubleword load.

Comment: Even on a CPU that faults for the OS to handle misaligned accesses, that's required to be transparent so the OS isn't going to deliver a signal.  (RISC-V requires unaligned loads to at least appear to work, even if it's via emulation in a fault handler.)  So the only observable effect would be performance.  Which you could test by running it in a loop.  Compile with optimization enabled, and use `volatile` for the actual aligned vs. unaligned load. (And check the asm for sanity.)  It might be the same speed, half speed (HW supported), or hundreds of times slower (emulated.)

Comment: Thanks for your advise Peter! I had a try. And is seems that MDA will be processed by hardware transparently. One million such MDAs use about 16s, and one million normal data access use about 10s.

Comment: One million normal loads took 10 seconds?  Does this CPU run at 0.1 MHz or something (Or 0.5MHz with loop overhead)?  Or have no cache and slow memory?  That seems extremely slow.  But assuming your microbenchmark was constructed properly so it was actually timing a real effect, seeing a 1.6x difference is pretty solid evidence that it's handled in hardware.

Comment: Sorry, I think it's about 1250 million normal loads.