# Encrypt strings in pure C in order to hide them in the executable

Tags: c, visual-studio-2008, encryption

I am trying to avoid literal strings from appearing in the executable. I want to put a string encrypted in the executable and then decrypt and use it at runtime. I read a bit into [How to hide a string in binary code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1356896/how-to-hide-a-string-in-binary-code) and http://bytes.com/topic/c/answers/222096-hiding-string-compiled-code, but this is not exactly what I want.

Could it be done using macros? For example, I can declare a wide char string using

```
wchar_t str[] = L"value"
```

or

```
wchar_t *str = L"value"
```

and magical `L` will convert chars to widechars. Is it possible to create another magical `L` like this to make encrypted strings? E.g:

```
ENC"value"
```

For the moment I am defining already encrypted strings as macros:

```
#define SAMPLE_STRING "ftnurd eru etrth" /*Random chars for imitating encryption*/
```

and passing them to a normal function like

```
char *decstr(char *data)
```

Is there an easier method to do this?

I am using Windows XP SP3 with Visual C++ 2008 Express.

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply create an encryption and decryption function? Then you could write something like

```
char *hidden_password = my_encrypt("pAsSw0rd");
puts(hidden_pasword); // "aCud5Ttei23w8D"
// ...
char *real_password = my_decrypt("aCud5Ttei23w8D");
puts(real_password); // "pAsSw0rd"
```

**However,** it's not a good idea to store hard-wired text strings in your executable if they contain sensitive data. Also, don't reinvent the wheel - before rolling your very own encryption method, try some established, high-quality, cryptographically secure libraries like [OpenSSL](http://www.openssl.org/).

Comment: but if i pass "pAsSw0rd" to normal function, i can find string "pAsSw0rd" in my executable. This example will read "pAsSw0rd" from file (or it is already loaded in memory) and store encrypted result in memory.

Comment: @DjJeshk That was just an example. The point is, if you need `"pAsSw0rd"`, then you encrypt it, then store the **encrypted** string in the executable, then you decrypt it at run-time to find the original, non-encrypted string.

Comment: If I have much more strings to encrypt, i have to put already encrypted strings in the executable. Would not be easier to use some DontKnowHowToWriteThis macro?

Comment: @DjJeshk Why do you think a macro would solve your problem? Macros are not magic. You won't be able to hammer in raw data and have encrypted strings in the binary all of a sudden.

Comment: A text from http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Macros.html : _A macro is a fragment of code which has been given a name. Whenever the name is used, it is replaced by the contents of the macro._ My guess is that macros are _executed_ before any real compilation begins.

Comment: @DjJeshk No, they aren't. They are substituted the text they are `#define`d.

Comment: And what about http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Macro-Arguments.html#Macro-Arguments ?

Comment: @DjJeshk Well, what about them?

Comment: I know i can process each char seperately 
    char test[5] = {E('T'), E('e'), E('s'), E('t'), '\0'}    
but why not
    char test[5] = ENC("Test")    
?