# String modification in C++ macro

Tags: c++, string, macros

Is there a way to modify a string literal in C++ from macro?

The reason for that is obfuscating code, particularly, 2 mutex wishes:

1. I want to see literals as is in my source code, say, "password123".
2. I want them to be mangled somehow before compilation to avoid including them in binaries.

I know that primitive modifications like XOR or shifting cannot be enough for professional analysis, but they are good enough for me.

Comment: Not I'm aware of doing such manipulation with the c++ preprocessor.

Comment: I could see it being possible if the string were in the format `(p,a,s,s,w,o,r,d,1,2,3)` or `(p)(a)(s)(s)(w)(o)(r)(d)(1)(2)(3)` or some other format that separates characters. You would finish by stringizing the result.

Comment: Not unless you have the password decomposed into separate characters, if written as a string in the source they will constitute a preprocessing token which won't come apart during preprocessing.

Comment: You could probably achieve such a transformation with a bit of template metaprogramming, similar to that used for typesafe printf.  I'll try and hunt down an appropriate link.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1356896/how-to-hide-a-string-in-binary-code?lq=1) question is similar, but this isn't a duplicate so I've reopened it.

Answer (score 3):

You could create a macro that doesn't really do anything, but use the macro as a "marker" for a custom build step (simple script might do it) to obfuscate the strings prior to the preprocessor getting the source code.

Comment: Actually, after obfuscuation the replacement string should be wrapped in a de-obfuscuator.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the macro to pass the string to a `constexpr` function which does the "encryption." Since C++14, `constexpr` is much easier to use.

```
// Similar to std::array, but with a member pointer as an accessor.
// It's complicated.
template< std::size_t length >
struct string_holder {
    char str[ length ];
    char const * ptr = str;
};

template< std::size_t length >
constexpr string_holder< length > encrypt( char const (& in)[ length ] ) {
    string_holder< length > result = {};
    for ( std::size_t i = 0; i != length - 1; ++ i ) {
        result.str[ i ] = in[ i ] ^ 1; // Do encryption here.
    }
    return result;
}

#define ENCRYPT( STR ) ( encrypt( STR ).ptr )

char const * const & s = ENCRYPT( "password123" );
```

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3b6f6753d9f722cb

Note, `s` needs to be declared as a `const&` reference to take advantage of lifetime extension. You could also write `auto const& s` or `auto &&s`; it would be the same. The current version of Clang does not allow `s` to be declared `constexpr`, but I believe this to be a bug.

*Ideally*, you could just write a user-defined literal like `"password123"_encrypted`. Unfortunately, progress on implementing the underlying language features for that is slow.