# Is defining a value in C a security issue?

Tags: c, security, c-preprocessor

If I were to have a program where I used:

```
#define SECRETNUMBER "1234567890"
```

Would this be a potential security issue/vulnerability?

I have this bit of code with this define statement and naturally it seemed to me that since this information is just defined right at the top without encryption or anything, this might be a security risk. I just wanted to know what the exact reason is and how this might be exploited?

Comment: What do you mean by “private” and “secure”? What is your program going to do with this “secret number”? And what are the threats you want to guard against?

Comment: This isn't even a variable... it's a macro

Comment: Your question is not even wrong.

Comment: No it's not. You're asking about "secure", not "safe" and this is far from it. "Secure" is much harder than what you'd think, explain your case better

Comment: As others have pointed out, that line of code does not do anything in itself because it is just a macro. But I guess you are really asking whether string literals can be extracted from the final binary. The answer is yes it can. And very easily too. This may be relevant: [How to hide a string in binary code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1356896/how-to-hide-a-string-in-binary-code)

Comment: No, it's not secure, in fact if you open the binary with an editor you can see something like `^?ELF^B^A^A^@^@^B^@1234567890`

Comment: Why was this closed? It's perfectly clear what he's asking and all you guys whining about defining terms and so forth need to re-read the question. He simply asked _is it a potential security issue/vulnerability?_  The answer is yes. An explanation of why it's a potential vulnerability would make a good answer.

Answer (score 2):

No it's not secure, anywhere the macro was used it would be substituted in plain  (readable) form.  For data to be secure it needs to be encrypted somehow, so that it cannot be read without knowledge of the decryption key.

Comment: That begs the question: How will the encryption key be made secure?

Comment: By not storing them on any device you don't physically control.  If your crypto key is built into your app and can be used without some piece of data coming from a user or server, its insecure.

Comment: @zaph It would beg the question if we were spec'ing a solution. But we're not. We're answering a very narrow question with a very well defined answer.

Answer (score -1):

Obviously it's not secure since it's visible in your code.  Let me add that once you add computations in your C preprocessor you also create side effects that may affect security. I suggest you this the secret number so that even if it is compromised,

Create a salt by generating a random piece of data.
Apply the salt to the secret number
Generate the hash for the salted password.
Store the secret number, the hash and the salt in the data store