# Cython after build still open SQL String

Tags: python, sql, cython

I want to create some extensions. I created a file called `reports.py`, and built it with Cython. It produced `reports.xxxx.pyd`, and I can import it to other python apps. [I followed these instructions](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/source_files_and_compilation.html).

I want to hide the SQL String that appears in the source code from the compiled binary, but it still appears there when I open it in a text editor:

The SQL string in `reports.py` file that I want to hide:
[image: The SQL string in reports.py file that I want to hide]

After build with cython, `reports.xxx.pyd` file:
[image: After build with cython, reports.xxx.pyd file]

`.pyd` file opened with notepad:
[image: .pyd file opened with notepad]

How can I hide the SQL String after building with Cython? Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

What you're asking for cannot be done by Cython. Cython is not intended to obfuscate code. Refer to the following post for ideas about how to hide strings that appear in your source code:

[How to hide a string in binary code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1356896/how-to-hide-a-string-in-binary-code)

Perhaps you could write a [C extension module](https://docs.python.org/3/extending/extending.html), or a Cython module (with a `.pyx` extension), and apply some of the techniques from the above post to it.

Comment: hi, thank you for answer and edited my question now it's look nice, oke now i understand.
i want to ensure, maybe there is a way out there that can do it. Thank you..