# combining to types of variables in c++

Tags: c++, variables

I'm trying to create a system which receives a password to give you access to a certain file. now I'm having trouble at the start. is there any variable that I can use to combine both numbers and letters? for example something that will store the password "25j3d3".
Thank you for your time.

Comment: `std::string`, `std::array`, `std::vector`, `std::tuple`, `std::pair` your own custom `struct`/`class`.. do you need more than that?

Comment: Sounds like you could use a [good C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: Why not just use an `std::string`?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to store the individual character types in separate variables (letters, numbers, punctuation) etc. separately. An `std::string` can hold all character types (it is even binary safe):

```
std::string password = "abc.,+123\xFF";
```

On a tangent, for storing and processing passwords, [obfuscating your code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1648618/techniques-for-obscuring-sensitive-strings-in-c) may be a desired effect.