# Single query to win32 api that always returns same value

Tags: c++, winapi

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to hide strings in a exe or a dll?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/926172/how-to-hide-strings-in-a-exe-or-a-dll)

I am looking for a win32api call, that will always return the same value, preferably a value viewable as a string, but other types are ok also. It must return the same value whether executed from Windows XP SP2 in Spanish or Windows 7 in English. I couldn't find any, and was hoping to get some help.

I'm trying to hide strings in a C++ application by finding a constant variable from the API that will be equal across XP/7 & different languages, to serve as the base of the encryption.

Comment: `CloseHandle(NULL);` returns `0`.

Comment: Why do you need this? [What is your actual problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/149668) If you so desperately need it, why does it have to come from the Windows API? Why not just write `const char* TestFoo() { return "Hello World!"; }` or something like that yourself?

Comment: I'm trying to hide strings in a C++ application by finding a constant variable from the API that will be equal across XP/7 & different languages, to serve as the base of the encryption.

Comment: The suspense is killing me, and I know I'll regret asking this, but if it is so predictable, might that not tell you something about how well it will provide an encryption base?

Comment: I think he doesn't want to hard code a key in.  A Windows call will look innocuous.  Maybe he could do a strlen on a phrase.

Comment: The systemwide of per-user cryptographics keystore. It is a standard windows feature.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to imagine someone taking the time to add such a function, which by definition is unnecessary, to an API.

My first guess would be reserved fields or obsolescent functions, but the former are always 0 and the latter are hard to depend upon.

That said...

- [FormatMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679351%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with a constant (or neutral) language ID and error code?
- [GetLocaleInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318101%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)(LOCALE_INVARIANT, LOCALE_ILDATE, ...)?

Answer (score 0):

For my AES-based encryption code, I based my keys on a custom-written random number generator that generates the same value every time it is called.  Makes it harder to analyse the code statically to figure out the logic, but creates a consistent value dynamically at runtime so it is not stored in the app statically at compile-time.